# Create column to get unique counts for a column per unique id

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I have a postgre sql table that has the following columns:

```
 person_id|date     |cat      

 1489358  |12-29-19 |tier1
 1489358  |12-29-19 |tier2
 1489350  |01-09-20 |tier1
 1489350  |01-09-20 |tier1
```

I want to create an extra column where I create a column to count the unique categories per person id. So the table would look like:

```
 person_id|date     |cat      |ct_cat
 1489358  |12-29-19 |tier1.   |2
 1489358  |12-29-19 |tier2    |2
 1489350  |01-09-20 |tier1.   |1
 1489350  |01-09-20 |tier1.   |1
```

I tried the following code:

```
select distinct *, count(distinct cat) as ct_cat
into table_2
from table_1
group by person_id, date,  cat;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could simply do:

```
select t1.*, count(distinct cat) over (partition by person_id)
from table_1 t1;
```

However, Postgres does not support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  There is a simple work-around using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t1.*,
       (dense_rank() over (partition by person_id order by cat asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by person_id order by cat desc) 
       ) as num_cat
from table_1 t1;
```